# jquery copy value from img tag to input tag

Tags: jquery, input, duplicates, tags, copy

I need to put a value in a input tag from a data tag from img tag.[image]

As you can see, I want to clik on a small icon, and I want to feel the input tag #source.

The code from the img tag the desired value is in a data tag data-sourceori

```
<td><img src="'.base_url().'images/function-icons/page_copy.png" data-sourceori="'.$mot->source.'" title="Ajouter à partir de source '.$mot->source.'" alt="Ajouter à partir de source '.$mot->source.'" width="25"/></td>
```

The code from the input tag target id="source"

```
<input type="text" class="<?php echo form_error('source', ' ', ' '); ?>" value="<?php echo set_value('source', $mot->source); ?>" name="source" id="source" maxlength="100" width="50%"/>
```

The jquery code

```
$("img").click(function(){
var dataValue = $(this).data("sourceori");
$("input#source").val(dataValue);
```

I tried quite a lot of solution, but I'm very bad in jquery.

Nothing works.

Thanks for your help

Patrice

Comment: As you're asking a jquery/javascript question, it would be easier for you (and us) to view, and provided in the question, the *rendered HTML*.   There may be an issue with the php tags.   Then create a runable snippet that fully demonstrates the issue (ie, it not working...which can be hard to demonstrate)

Comment: Your jquery, as provided, works fine  https://jsfiddle.net/Lvp7ber4/.   So there must be some other issue - have you checked the browser console for errors (F12 in browser)?

Comment: Hello, thank's for the answer, the php code works fine, I have just a problem with my need. I tried to put the whole code of the page but I can't, sorry

Comment: As noted, your code, *as provided*, works fine - the only thing not provided is the *rendered* HTML (and all the other components on your page),  Your jquery (which you've asked about) does not have any problems other than obvious missing `})` which would be picked up in the browser console.

Comment: I try the console, but when I click, nothing append.

Comment: *nothing works* - it will generally do *something* - it might be an error (eg `$ is not defined`), or it might call your click handler but *appear* to copy nothing (if `data-sourceori="'.$mot->source.'"` is blank `data-sourceori=""` would *appear* to do nothing) - add some debug code inside the click handler, eg `console.log("clicked")` - is your click handler being fired?   Without a snippet that *demonstrates* the issue, the rest is just speculation as a working fiddle with *your* code has been provided.

Comment: If you view the image element in the DOM inspector do you see the expected `data-sourceori` attribute?